# Managing multi sites in cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

Following are the three country based sites I am having -

Site 1 - https://example.com/uk

Site 2 - https://example.com/fr

Site 3 - https://example.com/ie

All 3 sites are using same code base and on the basis of country (`uk` | `fr` | `ie`) in my code I am passing some default configuration, like country specific text and some feature enable/disable switch etc. to the inner pages.

In my cypress, I have created `fixtures` like -

**/fixtures** -

```
  /uk
    -uk-config.json

  /fr
    -fr-config.json

  /ie
    -ie-config.json
```

I am stuck with the folder structure in `integration` folder and do not know the recommended way of doing this. Please help me on this.

**Option 1-**

**/integration** -

```
/uk
  -homepage.spec.js
  -plp.spec.js
  -pdp.spec.js
  -cart.spec.js


/fr
  -homepage.spec.js
  -plp.spec.js
  -pdp.spec.js
  -cart.spec.js


/ie
  -homepage.spec.js
  -plp.spec.js
  -pdp.spec.js
  -cart.spec.js
```

Problem with this approach - Though this code is more segregated on country basis, but here lot of code duplicates and it get increases as we launch other country stores.

**Option 2 -**

**/integration -**

```
  -homepage.spec.js
  -plp.spec.js
  -pdp.spec.js
  -cart.spec.js
```

And in this pass, country specific configurations from fixtures. TBH, I don't know how can I manage this and it would really be good if someone find this is a better way and can provide some pointers toward this would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
If I understood your problem clearly, you want to run your same set of tests but for different countries and you are facing issues in reading and there is a problem that suite gets increased if too many countries will be added just to test same set of tests. Right ??

**Solution:**
You can pass the `COUNTRY` variable as node env variable from command line and assign that as Cypress env variable and read it in your tests.

```
"test": "COUNTRY=$COUNTRY ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open --env COUNTRY=$COUNTRY"
```

Your run command should be like below

```
COUNTRY=fr npm run test
COUNTRY=in npm run test
COUNTRY=uk npm run test
COUNTRY=whatever npm run test
```

```
let json = require('config.json');
export const getCountryUrl = () => {
  return json[Cypress.env().COUNTRY]['url']
}
```

```
{
  "uk": {
    "url": "https://uk-website"
  },
  "fr": {
    "url": "https://fr-website"
  }
}
```